# R cutree on dendrogram with "centroid" and "median" methods yields more clusters than expected

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I want to test the hierarchical clustering with "centroid" and "median" methods. I have the following R code:

```
library(dendextend)

iris <- datasets::iris
iris2 <- iris[,-5]
species_labels <- iris[,5]

d_iris <- dist(iris2)
hc_iris <- hclust(d_iris, method = "centroid")

dend <- as.dendrogram(hc_iris)
dend <- color_branches(dend, k=3)

plot(dend, 
    main = "Clustered Iris data set
    (the labels give the true flower species)", 
    horiz =  TRUE,  nodePar = list(cex = .007))
```

The number of clusters seems to be larger than the `k` in the `color_branches` function.

[image]

However, if I do the `cutree` directly on `hc_iris`, which is the result of hierarchical clustering:

```
table(cutree(hc_iris, k=3), iris$Species)
```

I get 3 clusters, as expected:

```
   setosa versicolor virginica
     50          0         0
     0         50        48
     0          0         2
```

But if I apply the `cutree` function on the dendrogram, the number of clusters is 34:

```
table(cutree(as.dendrogram(hc_iris), 3), iris$Species)
setosa versicolor virginica
   4          0         0
   3          0         0
   3          0         0
   6          0         0
   2          0         0
   3          0         0
  10          0         0
   5          0         0
   4          0         0
   1          0         0
   1          0         0
   2          0         0
   1          0         0
   3          0         0
   2          0         0
   0          3         0
   0         27         9
   0         12         0
   0          2         0
   0          3         0
   0          1         3
   0          2         0
   0          0         9
   0          0         3
   0          0         6
   0          0         2
   0          0         3
   0          0         3
   0          0         3
   0          0         2
   0          0         2
   0          0         2
   0          0         1
   0          0         2
```

This happens with both "centroid" and "median" methods.

Comment: I think what you are doing _should_ work. Bug?  but a work-around is this. Change your color_branches statement to `dend <- color_branches(dend, clusters=cutree(hc_iris,3))`